# Completely reset my Desire HD

Tags: factory-reset, htc-desire-hd

I have been trying for some time the ICS Rom from the Team Blackout, but Im not very happy to it. I would like to go back to how my phone was when i bought it. I'd like to make a TOTAL reset. That means:

- No media saved
- No accounts saved
- No settings saved
- No apps saved
- Original Android 2.3 back

Basically, as it was when I unboxed it. Is this possible? If anyone could give me some instructions, I'd be very thankful. I'm not much of an expert in working with Android systems (A friend helped me "root it") and Im not sure how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make a backup of your phone before flashing the ROM?

Comment: Not that I know of. Does it mean its impossible to go back now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell from research you should be able to download the RUU from [here](http://shipped-roms.com/download.php?category=android&model=Ace&file=RUU_Ace_Sense30_S_HTC_WWE_3.12.405.1_Radio_12.65.60.29_26.14.04.28_M_release_225512_signed.exe) and run it. This requires a Windows computer as it is a .exe file.

Download the file to your computer, plug your phone in to your computer and run the file. It should return your phone to the latest factory shipped OS and remove root.

Comment: I dont know what RUU is, but I will do it. When I connect it, what mode should I chose? "Charge only"?

Comment: No what ever enables your computer to see it.

Comment: "Mount drive" then, i guess

Comment: What carrier is your phone on?

Comment: My carrier is O2, in Germany. Im about to do it. Should I not?

Comment: No that should be fine, it's the file for the World Wide Edition, which should cover that. I don't see an O2 specific file. If it is the wrong file it should do nothing.

Comment: Its telling me its not finding no connection to an Android phone, even though I can see it under "my Pc". Do I need some other setting?

Comment: Try installing HTC Sync 3.0 from HTC's website. It could be a driver issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7580/discussion-between-dbugger-and-znewman)

Comment: I keep getting error 155 :(

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the most easy tasks, and is called *Factory Reset*. Depending on your Android version, you find the suitable item at different places in the device's *Settings* menu:

- Android 4.0 has it in *Backup and Reset* (at the end of that screen, watch out for "personal data")
- Android 2.3 placed it in *Privacy* (with a fence-symbol; again at the end of that page)

There are also ways to achieve this without going via the settings menu, booting into *Recovery Mode*. [hard-reset.com](http://www.hard-reset.com/) mentions the appropriate procedures for most devices.

Comment: Ive already tried that, but only resets the Custom Rom. It doesnt bring me back to Android 2.3 that I had in the beginning

Comment: No, that's not possible that way: If you flashed a custom ROM (or any ROM, for that case), the original "ROM" gets overwritten. No way to restore that, except if you made a (Nandroid) backup before. Only other thing you can do then is to obtain the stock ROM (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)) and re-flash it.